# Broken Permalinks in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Instead of outputting the posts as

`example.com/2017/02/title`

it outputs it as

`example.com/201702title`

right now posts only open as

`example.com/title`

I'm using https://github.com/biomadeira/jasper template

Answer (score 1):

In `_config.yml` it has the following permalink:

```
permalink: /:title
```

That means it will generate posts urls based in their titles.

To have them in this form `example.com/2017/02/title` you need to change the permalink definition, you have several predefined types for example:

- `permalink: date` generates `example.com/2017/02/title`

You have more combinations [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/)

## update

Tested it locally and found the error, the correct permalink value would be just `date`, you can check post links are working right with:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
{{post.url}}
{% endfor %}
```

But the site is using urls from a custom **tag** plugin in: https://github.com/biomadeira/jasper/blob/master/_plugins/jekyll-catgenerator.rb which does not handle this and generates wrong urls for posts, you can fix the generator or avoid using it, using instead something like the previous code.

Comment: `permalink: date` still generates `example.com/201702title` `permalink: :date' outputs `example.com/:date`. There are no forward slashes in the url

Comment: Does the post has a `permalink` also? Or you can try to post the contents of your `_config.yml` and `post` to see what is happening.

Comment: no `permalink` in the post. My config.yml is the exact same as the author's. The only thing I changed was mostly all in css. Otherwise the rest is untouched.

Comment: What is the exact name of the file and its location?

Comment: All post titles are affected the same way. What do you mean by location?

Comment: forgot to mention that after I open the post `example.com/201702title`all I have to do for that post to generate is just add a forward slash and the post works

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: not adept at how to fix a generator would removing the plugin from the folder solve my problem? And I'm assuming `{% for post in site.posts %}{{post.url}}{% endfor %}` would be placed in my `post.html` in `_layouts`?

Comment: @WinterJules you should need to remove the plugin and change the way the site display its pages, it is not that trivial I suggest you use another theme that doesn't change the way Jekyll handle posts natively.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because your template is [configured](https://github.com/biomadeira/jasper/blob/master/_config.yml#L29) that way.

The solution is to simply comment out this permalink definition when Jekyll will fallback to the default `date` setting.